# Jquery tabs keep tab open that is subid in url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i am using jquery tabs, and trying to get pagination in each one, everything works fine however, if i click to go to the next page on say the second tab, it does it fine, but transports me to the first tab open, so you have to keep clicking to the second tab to view the new content. My question is how can i make it so that when the user clicks the next page in the pagination, the content is refreshed but the same tab is left open.

My plan on how to incorporate this into my current code is to use the url `mail.php?page=2&tid=2`

Where the page=2 is reference for the pagination that works fine but i want the tid (tab id) to make it so that that tab is the open one.

Here is the javascript for the tabs you might recognise it

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

And the html for the tabs (had to comment out for the lists)

```
//<div id="tabsX">   <div id="tabContent">   <ul class="tabs">
   // <!--<li><a id="all" href="#all" class="all">All</a></li>-->
   // <li><a href="#inbox" class="inbox"></a></li>
   // <li><a href="#outbox" class="outbox"></a></li>
   // <li><a href="#compose" class="compose"></a></li>
    //<li><a href="#trash" class="trash"></a></li>
   // 

   // </ul>
```

AND the html for the tab content (only showing one as an example with no content as there will be too much to show)

```
<div id="inbox" class="tab_content">
      <div id="inbox_header" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
      <!---content--->          

      </div><!---end inbox_content--->



</div><!---end inbox--->
```

I would really appreciate any help as i can't seem to find any solutions for myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/344304) to catch the `tid` param in javascript

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then change your code like this

```
var tabIndex = parseInt(getParameterByName('tid'),10);
$("ul.tabs li").eq(tabIndex - 1).addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content").eq(tabIndex - 1).show(); //Show first tab content
```

So you full `js` code would be

```
function getParameterByName(name)
    {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
      var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
      if(results == null)
        return "";
      else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    } 
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content

    var tabIndex = parseInt(getParameterByName('tid'),10);
    if(!tabIndex)
       tabIndex = 1;
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(tabIndex - 1).addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content").eq(tabIndex - 1).show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    //  add you onlick code here


  )};
```

I am adding `-1` in `eq` because it's `0-based`. Check the doc here [$.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: ok great, but quick question where you say change the code, do you mean completely replace the whole code with what you provided, or just change the different parts?

Comment: Hi, right ok i entered all the code works ok, but when you first enter the page like www.site.com/mail.php all it shows is the tab header, with no content, where it should show the first tab content. If you then go and click on another tab afterwards then all works well and you can carry on going through all the tabs fine, I am not sure how to fix this part, i am guessing though it may be quite easy for you. Thanks for all your help, hipefully we can just fix this last issue. EDIT: Forgot to mention all the subids (tid=2) etc... all works fine its just when there are no subids there are errors

Comment: Updated the code. Just add `if(!!tabIndex) tabIndex = 1;` in the right place as added in the code. That will make `tabindex 1` when there is no `tid` in url and will keep `first tab` and it's `content` open.

Comment: ok brilliant that works, great, the only thing i had to change was remove the second ! in the if, just for future reference for others with the same problem. Thankyou so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the documentation for jquery tabs. There's a number of options that you can use. The cookie option:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

> Store the latest selected tab in a cookie. The cookie is then used to determine the initially selected tab if the selected option is not defined. Requires cookie plugin, which can also be found in the development-bundle>external folder from the download builder. The object needs to have key/value pairs of the form the cookie plugin expects as options. Available options (example): { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true }. Since jQuery UI 1.7 it is also possible to define the cookie name being used via name property.

Also, you can use the selected option. This lets you specify what tab should be opened on initialization:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 3 });
```

The third option is to load the content of the tab via an ajax call instead.

Comment: I should add that the 3 in the "selected" option would need to be supplied. You tagged the question as having PHP so you would replace the 3 with <?php echo isset($_GET['tid'])?$_GET['tid']:-1; ?>